# SQLAlchemy ORM ClauseElement select column 1, where column 2 in table 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Very new to Flask, SQLAlchemy ORM and ClauseElement usage. Still not sure how to ask the question....

I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent would be for SQLAlchemy ORM? I've been through the SQLAlchemy documentation which is daunting if you're new to it and just simply not sure which SQLAlchemy implement to use.

```
test_strings = ["red", "green", "blue"]
for strings = test_strings:

    select COLUMN2 from TABLE1 where COLUMN4 = strings;
```

I'd like to achieve the result of having a list of items in COLUMN2 FOR EACH item in COLUMN4. So it would look something like this visually.

```
blue: Plumbs
red: Pairs, red-grapes, Strawberries
green: Mangos, watermellons, green-grapes
```

Comment: It'll help people answer your question, if you take the time to produce a [mcve]. In other words include table/model class definitions needed to answer your question. While your current question in a way holds some of that implicitly already, it'll be easier to try and understand what you're after, if given more data to work with. Also don't forget to add what DB you are using. Answers might depend heavily on that.

Comment: Thanks Ilja! If this is not good enough let me know. I'm can't put up the actual code but if code is absolutely necessary then I'm happen to write it completely new and post it.